# Space between each character in Teradata mLoad target table

Tags: sql, csv, teradata, mload, bteq

I am loading a flat file into Teradata target table.

Example flat file:

```
Employee_ID, Employee_First_Name, Employee_Salary
1,Jay,50000
2,Sam,60000
3,Tom,70000
```

The result of the mload looks as such in the Teradata target table.

```
 1 , J a y , 5 0 0 0 0 
 2 , S a m , 6 0 0 0 0
 3 , T o m , 7 0 0 0 0
```

All target fields are specified as Varchar(1024).

Has anyone encountered something similar?

I was expecting the data to load as existed on the physical flat file.

Comment: What is the character set of your character columns in your target table?  First thought is you are loading UTF to Latin.

Comment: Perhaps you are loading UTF-16 input data with ASCII session character set - in which case those "spaces" are really x'00' not x'20' (you can check that using CHAR2HEXINT function on an initial SUBSTRING). Your session character set should match your input, and if you have non-LATIN characters then your target column should be CHARACTER SET UNICODE.